# How can I save my file to the directory I just created?

Tags: python, linux, directory, data-processing

I created a directory that is named by the date and time. I am trying to save my file into the directory with this code:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
mydir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M'))
os.makedirs(mydir)
os.chdir(mydir)
for x in FSBRID:
    FSBRws2['L12'] = x
    a=str(x)
    FSBR.save(mydir + a + '.pdf')
```

The result is that the file is not saved in the directory I created, but it is saved in the directory before that. It also names the file: 2020-07-20_11-333257.pdf, and the directory I created is named: 2020-07-20_11-33.

Comment: What is FSBRws2? Since you `chdir` into `mydir` you likely don't want to add that to the file name being saved. `FSBR.save(a + ".pdf")` is more like what you want. I don't know why its going into the parent directory, though. Is this `FSBR` thing initialized with a path?

Comment: You need to put a directory separator between directory name and file name, and that varies across operating systems. The Pythonic way of constructing a filesystem path takes care of such cosiderations for you: `os.path.join()`.

Comment: FSBR is initialized with a path, and it did not affect the result to remove the directory from the file name. FSBRws2 is the worksheet inside of FSBR. I tried os.path.join(), but I am not seeing any changes either:     report=os.path.join(mydir, a + '.pdf')
    FSBR.save(report)                                                                                                      The operating system is Linux->pycharm->python